# Cocos2D freezes on iPhone 4

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, freeze, iphone-4

I have a Cocos2d app (1.0.1) that breaks on my iPhone 4 running iOS 4.2.8.  It is working fine in the 4.1, 4.3, and 5.0 simulators.  It works fine on iPhone 3g and iPod Touches running 4.2.1 also.  But it breaks a different way on the 4.2 sim.

On my phone it freezes when I attempt to set up the GL view and hook the director & scene up to it.  There's no error and no easy explanation of what went wrong.  In the 4.2 simulator, the OpenGL view in question is simply blank but there is no freezing.

The freeze isn't even a "crash," exactly.  It simply freezes up, then about 60-75 seconds later it unfreezes and continues as if nothing is awry at all.  After the device unfreezes, all my inputs seem to have been buffered up because they then all go through in sequence (including screenshots, sleeping the phone, hitting the Home button, etc)

Also, the app itself works perfectly after the unfreeze.  But,the game is only supposed to last 60 seconds, so at first it didn't appear to be working at all because it'd be in some weird state because it was frozen when the game was supposed to end.  But then just for debug purposes I lengthened the game time limit to 95 seconds left and it is totally playable after the unfreeze (usually when there's 15 seconds left) and seems to work flawlessly at that point.

Here's the viewWillAppear method where it freezes.  (I do virtually nothing in init:)

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if (self.view.subviews.count == 0)
    {
        UIImageView *scoreAreaBackground = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ScoreBar" ofType:@"gif"]]];
        scoreAreaBackground.frame = CGRectMake(0, CalculateScoreAreaTop(), GAME_SCREEN_WIDTH, CalculateScoreAreaHeight());
        [self.view addSubview:scoreAreaBackground];

        image1View = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(CalculateImageLeft(), CalculateImageTop(), CalculateImageWidth(), CalculateImageHeight())] retain];
        [self.view addSubview:image1View];

        EAGLView *glView = [EAGLView viewWithFrame:CGRectMake(CalculateGridX(gameParameters.boardWidth), CalculateGridY(gameParameters.boardHeight), CalculateGridWidth(gameParameters.boardWidth), CalculateGridHeight(gameParameters.boardHeight))
                                       pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGB565   // kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8
                                       depthFormat:0                        // GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16_OES
                            ];

        [self.view addSubview:glView];

        CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];
        [director setOpenGLView:glView];
        [director setAnimationInterval:1.0/60]; 
        [director setDisplayFPS:NO];

        ...
```

I incrementally commented out every piece of code, and the "offending" line is this one:

```
[director setOpenGLView:glView];
```

It doesn't actually freeze on executing that line.  I can debug and step through the entire viewWillAppear method, and it responds fine.  Then whenever I hit "Continue program execution" the app freezes.

What I mean by it's the offending line is that I can comment out everything following that (and all code referencing Cocos2d in the rest of the app) and it will freeze the device exactly as described.  Then if I comment out that line it works fine with no freeze - except of course there's nothing happening in my OpenGL view.

Does anyone have an idea what is wrong here?  It's particularly strange that this works fine on other devices and the simulator but doesn't work on just my phone, which makes me suspect some kind of build setting thing (I have it set to require armv6 since otherwise it wouldn't run on the older devices at all)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Update: Edits inline above.   I just realized the iPhone in question is running iOS 4.2.8, and I was not testing with the iOS 4.2 simulator.  In the iOS 4.2 simulator, it does not freeze, but I get a blank game screen.  In all the other simulators (4.1 thru 5) it works perfectly fine.  However, it works perfectly fine on an iPod Touch that is running iOS 4.2.1, so that seems strange.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to your problem, but suggestions of things you should do to try and exclude any freak error. First of all, I assume your devices are not jailbroken and you're not developing on a Hackintosh, right?

- clean and rebuild the project (Xcode: Product -> Clean)
- reboot the device
- reboot your Mac
- upgrade to Xcode 4.2 / iOS 5, in particular if you're still using an Xcode beta or Xcode 3.2
- try running on a different iPhone 4 (to ensure it's not just yours that has this issue)
- try creating a new Cocos2D project from scratch, see if the error occurs there as well

  - If the error goes away, copy source code and resources from your original project into this new project, until the new project works as expected. Then try that on your iPhone 4 to see if the issue was related to a Build Setting.
- step through the code line by line, to see which call actually takes this long. See: http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/10/xcode-4-debugging-crashcourse/

The simple fact that you're apparently able to select the iOS 4.1 Simulator may indicate that maybe something's wrong with your Xcode installation. With Xcode 4.2 the only Simulators you should be able to select are 4.3 and 5.0. As a last resort measure, delete the /Developer folder and reinstall Xcode.

Note that all build settings in your target that are printed in **bold** letters have changed from the default. You may want to compare the changed build settings with that of a newly created Xcode project, and revert the build settings accordingly.

If you're using Xcode 4.2 you should ensure that Apple LLVM 3.0 Compiler is the compiler, not LLVM GCC 4.2. If LLVM 3.0 gives you additional errors and warnings, fix those.